# Ruby. Split string in separate decimal numbers

Tags: ruby

I have a long string which contains only decimal numbers with two signs after comma

```
str = "123,457568,22321,5484123,77"
```

The numbers in string only decimals with two signs after comma. How I can separate them in different numbers like that

```
arr = ["123,45" , "7568,22" , "321,54" , "84123,77"]
```

Comment: I would use a regex but here's a non-regex solution: `i=0; str.count(',').times.each_with_object([]) { |_,a| j=str.index(',',i); a << str[i..j+2]; i = j+3 }  #=> ["123,45", "7568,22", "321,54", "84123,77"]`. See [String#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-index).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a regex split here:

```
str = "123,457568,22321,5484123,77"
nums = str.split(/(?<=,\d{2})/)
print nums
```

This prints:

```
123,45
7568,22
321,54
84123,77
```

The logic above says to split at every point where a comma followed by two digits precedes.

Answer (score 3):

### Scan String for Commas Followed by Two Digits

This is a case where you really need to know your data. If you *always* have floats with two decimal places, and commas are decimals in your locale, then you can use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#method-i-scan) as follows:

```
str.scan /\d+,\d{2}/
#=> ["123,45", "7568,22", "321,54", "84123,77"]
```

Since your input data isn't consistent (which can be assumed by the lack of a reliable separator between items), you may not be able to guarantee that each item has a fractional component at all, or that the component has exactly two digits. If that's the case, you'll need to find a common pattern that *is* reliable for your given inputs or make changes to the way you assign data from your data source into *str*.